# Links between mathematical folklore and educational success

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, student-motivation

I would like to ask if, in the research field of mathematical education, some work has been done to investigate the relationship between 1) and 2):

1. mathematical education and student motivation
2. the great quantity of "folkloristic" writing (so to say) on trivia and anecdotes about the mathematical community (e.g.  the ones collected in *Mathematical Apocrypha Redux* by Steven Krantz).

To be clear, I want to know if there are links between cultural stories of mathematics (which may have reached "apocryphal" status), and with student performance and/or motivation in mathematics in those cultures.

Comment: I've wondered if tales of absent-minded or single-minded or literal-minded mathematicians attracts the quirky (present company excepted!).

Comment: You might see [**this**](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1017523230758) (paywalled) and some of its sources. The citation is: Picker, S. H., & Berry, J. S. (2000). *Investigating pupils' images of mathematicians. Educational Studies in Mathematics, 43*(1), 65-94. (Also: You might check [**other studies**](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=4405766658824347516&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=0,22&hl=en) that cite it.)

Comment: Another place you might look would be in [**Mathematical People: Profiles and Interviews**](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-People-Interviews-Donald-Albers/dp/1568813406) to see how different mathematicians talk about their early inspiration.

Comment: I would say, accompanying parents to a grocery store, counting oncoming cars or figuring out whether contents of a round pot fits a square glass container is more productive than reading "folkloristic anecdotes".